# Entire site down - Seemingly random (and fatal) ExpressionEngine error

Tags: ee2, php, error, mysql, newrelic

Every so often, my entire site goes down for an indefinite period of time. Restarting the MySQL service appears to temporarily fix the issue. I recently upgraded to EE 2.7 and about the same time my website started to experiencing a bit of a slow down. Just when this error occurred, I noticed a huge spike in response time (1 million ms) for PHP processing in New Relic!

[image: 30 Minute Window for New Relic]
Above image shows a 30 hour window for New Relic

[image: An Error Was Encountered]

[image: 6 hour Window for New Relic]

This shows a 6 hour window for new relic

Any ideas on what could be happening? Any suggestions for diagnosing this? Remember, this error only occurs periodically and seemingly without warning.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this recurring error which was caused by huge traffic spikes ourselves by doubling the RAM from 2GB to 4GB (which spiked to 400% during heavy memory pressure) allocated to the VM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a backup or other cron process being run and this is overloading the database server?

Comment: Interesting. I only have a few cron jobs running and none of them would be causing this. According to New Relic, my memory spiked to over 3 times normal usage for an hour during this period, all due to httpd process using 830 Mb (1200 Mb total during this period). Also, it was the PHP time that spikes in the graphs above, not MySQL. It doesn't seem like database calls are affected time-wise.

Comment: I only mentioned the database as the error message shown is indicative of a connection problem. Something is blitzing out the connection to the server or between the web and database servers.

Comment: I had this issue with a poorly configured mysql server. If you can also watch the mysql connections when this happens, you'll probably see a whole bunch piled up behind a stuck one. I'm far from a dba, but check your mysql configuration.